# Regular expression to extract string from urls

Tags: regex

I need to extract a string from an URL. Here are some examples:

Input: https://www.example.net/eur_en/bas-026-009-basic-baby-hat-beige.html – Output: bas-026-009

Input: https://www.example.net/eur_en/aw18-245-b86-big-cherries-snow-jacket-plum-red.html – Output: aw18-245-b86

Input: https://www.example.net/eur_en/ss20-028-e70-hearts-tee-off-white-yellow.html – Output: ss20-028-e70

I want to be able to extract the string that goes from the first character after the "/eur_en/" until the third dash. Can someone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for regexp: `\/eur_en\/([^-]+-[^-]+-[^-]+)`

Play & test it at regex101: https://regex101.com/r/RvGROG/1

You need something like this:

```js
const urls = [
"https://www.example.net/eur_en/bas-026-009-basic-baby-hat-beige.html",
"https://www.example.net/eur_en/aw18-245-b86-big-cherries-snow-jacket-plum-red.html",
"https://www.example.net/eur_en/ss20-028-e70-hearts-tee-off-white-yellow.html",
]

const rg = new RegExp(`\/eur_en\/([^-]+-[^-]+-[^-]+)`)
const strs = urls.map(url => url.match(rg)[1])

console.log(strs)
// Output:
// [
//  "bas-026-009",
//  "aw18-245-b86",
//  "ss20-028-e70"
// ]
```

Of course, it's a simple example. In real cases don't forget to check that `.match` returned array with length greater than 1.
So, the first element is full captured string and the second (as third and next) it's a sub-strings, which is captured by parentheses.

We can improve and complicate our regex like so:
`\/((?:[^-\/]+-){2}[^-\/]+)`
It'll allow us to not to use a specific anchor `/eur_en/` and control the number of dash divided parts.

Answer (score 0):

The expression you're looking for is the following:

```
/(?<=eur_en\/)[^-]*-[^-]*-[^-]*/
```

Here is how it works:

- `(?<=eur_en\/)`: will look behind for `eur_env/` but will not use it in the output
- `[^-]*`: it will match any character that is not a dash. So it will get everything up to the **first** dash (not including the dash)
- `[^-]*`: it will match any character that is not a dash. So it will get everything up to the **second** dash (not including the dash)
- `[^-]*`: it will match any character that is not a dash. So it will get everything up to the **third** dash (not including the dash).

Answer (score 0):

```
/(?<=\/eur_en\/)\w+-\w+-\w+/g
```

| Tolkens | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `(?<=\/eur_en\/)` | <sup>Look behind - If `/eur_en/` is found, match whatever proceeds it.</sup> |
| `\w+-\w+-\w+` | <sup>One or more Word character = `[A-Za-z0-9]` and a literal hyphen three consecutive times.</sup> |

Review: https://regex101.com/r/Ge0zA3/1